# My lady, Your honour, Your grace, how to decide whether to use "my" or "your"?

Tags: word-usage

After watching some period dramas and courtroom dramas, I'm really confused of whether to use "*my*" or "*your*" when speak to someone with respect.

Are there some rules for these statements or are these just fixed patterns?

Comment: can you make it clearer?

Comment: @Maulik V Yes, I mean, why are they using `your honour` instead of 'my honour', and `my lady` instead of `your lady`, to me the circumstance and the context are almost the same, which is, they show some courtesy first, before speaking to the lady or the judge. I hope I've made it clear this time :)

Comment: Exact duplicate : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/why-is-it-your-majesty-but-my-lord

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<sub>It's crude but it can be simplified this way:</sub>

### My

Think Feudalism. Lords held lands and people tending their lands are under them. If you're taking care of the lord's land, then you have a lord. So you would say: *My Lord*. As if noting that: You are *my* lord.

### Your

You want to address the person having grace and honor. Saying *"My Honour"* or *"My Grace"* would sound like you're praising yourself.

Comment: This isn't a crude simplification at all. It's **exactly** how it works.

Comment: Wouldn't it normally be "Your Ladyship" rather than just "Your Lady"?

Comment: @PhilPerry Yes; because having a ladyship is very different from having a lady. ;)

Comment: Thanks helix, occasionally I also see "his Lordship", I think that also make sense according to your answer. :)

Comment: It is "Your Lordship" (the *state of being a Lord* is his) and "My Lord" (because he is that).

Answer (score 4):

For the British aristocracy the use of *my* or *your* depends upon whether the title is a specific rank or a general form of respect.

A holder of a rank of the nobility should be addressed with the form appropriate, for example a Duke, would be formally addressed as *Your Grace*.  The title is inherent in the rank of Duke.  Effectively the speaker is saying that "you are a Duke".

A holder of any noble rank may be addressed as *My Lord*.  Here the speaker is simply recognizing that the addressee is Lord over the speaker.  In other words, of higher rank.

Outside the nobility, for example a judge, the use of *Your Honour* recognizes that the post of judge deserves to be honoured - respected.

Comment: Have they stopped using "_Your Worship_" to address judges, and picked up the American "_Your Hono[u]r_"? I recall 20 or 30 years ago that an Australian was appearing in a New York City courtroom, and (as normal) addressed the judge as Your Worship. He got something of a tongue-lashing for appearing to try to ingratiate himself with the judge!